# MySQL hidden files on ubuntu taking up space

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a weird issue where my system (ubuntu 19) is showing that MySql 8 is using up 600gb of space, when it should be closer to 250gb.

I ran ubuntu's baobab utility in sudo mode, and it as well, is showing that MySQL is using up 250GB .  Any idea what could be taking up the other 250GB?

I also ran this query via SQL, to show table sizes - same story ~250GB, so not sure what else I could try.

```
SELECT 
     table_schema as `Database`, 
     table_name AS `Table`, 

     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

.. I do have a few indexes set up, but most of them on columns containing 0/1s

Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Is your innodb_file_per_table ON or OFF? Also, what's the size of the ibdata1 file?

Comment: file per table is on.  Not sure how to look up the size of ibdata1 yet for mysql 8/ubuntu .  But this should get me started.   thanks for pointing me, at least in A direction.

Comment: By default mysql install datadir is located at /var/lib/mysql so you can find ibdata1 there, if not there you can find it out by running "show variables like 'datadir';"

Comment: What are the largest few files?  (From this, we can more quickly diagnose what happened.)  Do this from the filesystem, not SQL.

Comment: Thanks everyone for tips - looks like ibdata is 'only' 20ish GB, however, there are a bunch of binlog.00### files, 1 to 14GB each, so looks like that might be the culprit.  going to research what those are now.

Comment: looks like this command worked for temporary solution:
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2019-10-19 22:46:26';
(mysql manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html )

still working on the long term solution.  Per mysql manual - these were the logs of select statements (which are typically huge in my case).  Not 100% yet on whether I need these :)

In either case, thank you everyone for helping troubleshoot.  This was blowing my mind for a bit, but all it took was browsing into the folder itself, and seeing hundreds of huge files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this command worked for temporary solution:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2019-10-19 22:46:26'; #your date
```

([mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html))

Still working on the long term solution. Per mysql manual - these were the logs of select statements (which are typically huge in my case). Not 100% yet on whether I need these :) In either case, thank you everyone for helping troubleshoot. This was blowing my mind for a bit, but all it took was browsing into the folder itself, and seeing hundreds of huge files!

Comment: Binary Logs do not store SELECTs. They store actual changes (`INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE` either as statements or row changes). The only exception is `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.